# Autopost multiple pins to Pinterest Board

Tags: php, automation, pinterest

I am using [PinterestPinner](https://github.com/dzafel/pinterest-pinner) to create an script that could login once and post multiple pins, rather than login each time I want to post a pin.

This is how I am using it:

```
foreach ($links as $link) 
{

    $pinterest = new PinterestPinner($username, $password);
    $result = $pinterest->pin(array(
        'board' => $boardId,
        'image' => $image,
        'description' => $description,
        'link' => $url,
    ));

    if (false === $result) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $pinterest->getError();
    } else {
        echo 'Pin Created, ID: ' . $pinterest->getPinID();
    }
}
```

I think using it this way makes the script login to Pinterest for every single pin. So for example, if I want to post 3 pins in a single script run, then it logs in 3 times rather than logging in once. (Please let me know if I am wrong about this).

How can I modify the script to keep the login session alive while posting multiple pins on my board?

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
try {
    $pinterest = new PinterestPinner\Pinner;
    $pin_id = $pinterest->setLogin('Your Pinterest Login')
        ->setPassword('Your Pinterest Password')
        ->setBoardID('Pinterest Board ID')
        ->setImage('Image URL')
        ->setDescription('Pin Description')
        ->setLink('Pin Link')
        ->pin();
} catch (PinterestPinner\PinnerException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```